# React ts Type 'Promise<X>' is missing the following properties from type 'X'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I am trying to to move my API request to a separate service, and faced this problem.

Here is my interface

```
export interface IProduct {
  id: any;
  productName: string;
  productDescription: string;
  productImage: string;
  productPrice: any;
  categoryId: string;
  category: any;
}
```

Here is components for list of products

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import {IProduct} from "../models"

interface IProps {
products: IProduct[];
}

export const ProductsList: React.FC<IProps> = ({products}) => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul className="posts">
        {products.map((products) => (
          <li key={products.id}>
            <h3>{products.productName}</h3>
            <p>{products.productDescription}</p>
            <h2>{products.productPrice}</h2>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductsList;
```

Next `Api.tsx` where I am trying making request:

```
import axios, { CancelTokenSource } from "axios";

import {IProduct} from "../models"
import React from 'react';

export const fetchAllProducts = async (setData: IProduct[]): Promise<IProduct[]> => {
  return axios.get<IProduct[]>("https://localhost:5001/api/ShowAllProducts")
    .then(response => {return setData = response.data });
}
```

and finally APP.tsx

```
import axios, { CancelTokenSource } from "axios";
import {IProduct} from "./models"
import {ProductsList} from "./components/ProductsList";
import React from 'react';
import {fetchAllProducts} from './services/api';

const defaultProps:IProduct[] = [];


function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<IProduct[]> 
    (defaultProps)

  const [loading, setLoading]: [boolean, (loading: boolean) => void] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError]: [string, (error: string) => void] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <ProductsList products= {fetchAllProducts(products)}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So i have an Error in app.tsx in return right before "=" symbol, on products.

It says:

```
Type 'Promise<IProduct[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'IProduct[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2740)
ProductsList.tsx(6, 5): The expected type comes from property 'products' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

Comment: `fetchAllProducts` returns ` Promise<IProduct[]>`. You're trying to pass that as a prop, which expects an `IProduct[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all guys, i figured it out, btw your answers made me understand one thing. i was thinking that

```
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<IProduct[]>(defaultProps)
```

is like typesriptish {set; get;} from .net lol.
but now i know tht second argument is function. so i just changed argument in my api.tsx file so it now accepts functions.

so component and interface remain without changes

here is my api.tsx

```
export const fetchAllProducts = async (func: any): Promise<IProduct[]> => {
return axios.get<IProduct[]> ("https://localhost:5001/api/ShowAllProducts")
.then(response => {return func(response.data)});}
```

and here is APP.tsx

```
const defaultProps:IProduct[] = [];

function App() {
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<IProduct[]>(defaultProps) 
const [loading, setLoading]: [boolean, (loading: boolean) => void] = 
React.useState<boolean>(true);
const [error, setError]: [string, (error: string) => void] = 
React.useState("");

React.useEffect(() => {
async () => await fetchAllProducts(setProducts);
}, [])

 return (
<div>
  <ProductsList products={products}/>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the line

```
.then(response => {return setData = response.data });
```

should be rewritten as:

```
.then(response => Promise.resolve(response.data));
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: thank you, i figured it out, i thought that second argument in const[X, Y] is just var, but it is function, so i changed my api arguments so it can accept func.

Answer (score 0):

Those properties that the error message mentioned as missing are the Array's properties.

```
interface IProps {
products: IProduct[];
}

export const ProductsList: React.FC<IProps> = ({products}) => {
...
}
```

In the code above you tell `ProductsList` component to expect *array* named products as a prop.

But in APP.tsx in the line

```
<ProductsList products= {fetchAllProducts(products)}/>
```

you send `fetchAllProducts(products)` as a `products` prop. `fetchAllProducts(products)` is a function that returns *promise*, not an *array*.

To fix it you could write something like:

```
  function App() {
    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState<IProduct[]> 
      (defaultProps)  
    const [loading, setLoading]: [boolean, (loading: boolean) => void] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
    const [error, setError]: [string, (error: string) => void] = React.useState("");

    React.useEffect(async () => {
      const allproducts = await fetchAllProducts();
      setProducts(allproducts)
      }, [])
  
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductsList products={products}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This way you fetch all products when the `App` component mounts and pass *array* as `products` prop to `ProductsList`.

Comment: thank you, i figured it out, i thought that second argument in const[X, Y] is just var, but it is function, so i changed my api arguments so it can accept func.